# How to save a .doc file many times with different names in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename, .doc

I have a .doc file in my folder. I want to save the same .doc file many times with different names.

Example:

I have a .doc file named `myfile.doc`.

I want it to be saved as `myfile1.doc`, `myfile2.doc`, `myfile3.doc`.

This needs to be done for up to 30 files like that.

How can I do this in Python?

I Tried this Script. But There is an Error:-

```
import shutil

dateoffile = input('Please Enter 4 Digit Date')
filenumber = input('Please Enter File Number')
hyphen1 = '-'
doctrname = 'KW'
hyphen2 = '-'
year = '2011'

original = 'dateoffile+hyphen1+doctrname+hyphen2+year.doc'
for i in range(1,31): # creates 30 files named from 1 to 30
    new = filenumber+i+'.doc' # the +i+ is used to have 30 different names and not crash
    shutil.copyfile(original, new) # You can even do original='pathtofile/orienter code hereginaldocfile.doc' and new='pathtonewfile/newdocfile'+i+'.doc'
```

Ther Error is :-

new = filenumber+i+'.doc' # the +i+ is used to have 30 different names and not crash
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Can You Explain Why it is Coming Like This ???

Comment: What did you try so far and where are you facing issues ? Could you post all that.

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this :

```
import shutil

original = 'myfile.doc'
number=int(input("Enter a number to name your files : "))
for i in range(1,31): # creates 30 files named from 1 to 30
    num = number+i
    new = 'myfile'+str(num)+'.doc' # the +num+ is used to have 30 different names and not crash
    shutil.copyfile(original, new) # You can even do original='pathtofile/originaldocfile.doc' and new='pathtonewfile/newdocfile'+str(num)+'.doc'
```

This should work

Comment: I Tried Your Code. I Modified Your Script. But it is Coming an Error. The Code is in my Question's Description

Comment: @Hacker--RohanRaj It looks normal , your `original` is just a string which doesn't change, what you have to do, is to get the `+` out of the string like this : `'dateoffile'+'hyphen1'+'doctrname'+'hyphen2'+'year.doc'`. When trying to copy this file, the code won't find your file, it is looking for a file named : `'dateoffile+hyphen1+doctrname+hyphen2+year.doc'` exaclty, it hasn't the value of the variables inside of it. And look at my code, I edited it, it tries to add int to a string, taht's my bad I didn't read twice ^^

Comment: Thank You For telling Me. But It is not Exactly What I Wanted. I Want That, if I Give Input as 1, the other file should be named as 2, other file should be named as 3.

I Am Telling That, If i Give Input as 3452, the output file should be named as 3453, and other output file should be named as 3454, other output file should be named as 3455. 1 should be added to the number.

Tell Me Solution If You Know

Comment: Here we go @Hacker--RohanRaj, you can now enter your number for your files

Comment: If Possible, Then Try to Answer This Question:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237307/python-docx-i-want-the-file-name-to-be-the-sum-of-input-and-integer-1